# exchanging data between UserControls , all tabbed children of the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I am new with WPF/C#, so this might be elementary to many of you. Please excuse my ignorance. If that is the case, all I need is a pointer to a simple code example that you think could help.
I searched this .. but was not able to find any existing solution that helped me, so I guess this is probably not the way of doing things ... 
I did similar stuff under C++, using pointers, which isn't something I was able to reproduce in C#.WPF

Anyway, here is what I am trying to do:
I have a main window with tabbed children, all of type UserControl, define in XAML

```
<Window x:Class="HighPerformanceScenarios.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HighPerformanceScenarios"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="Infragistics High-Performance XamDataGrid and XamDataChart" FontSize="20" Margin="0 10 0 10"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
            <TabItem Header="XamDataChart (Real-Time Data)" >
                <local:XamDataChartRealTimeData />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="RealTimeDisplay">
                <local:RealTimeDisplay />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="XamDataGrid High Performance">
                <local:XamDataGridHighPerformance />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Serial Port">
                <local:SerialPortClass />
            </TabItem>            
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This comes from a sample for high performance charting by Infragistics,

In one of the tabbed control items, the UserControl is a class that manages a serial port connection and handles the incoming data (100Hz stream of packets of doubles in binary form).
This UserControl (call it SerialPort) delegates to a separated thread (RunWorkerAsync... ) the task of reading the serial port , processing the binary stream and logging them to a file. This forever running thread reports back asynchronously to the SerialPort control each time a new packet is ready saved in a "locally available to the SerialPort control" dataRecord variable (double[18]).

The other UserControls are display controls. One is a set of gauges, another is a real-time chart and so on. All have their datasources (collections of data for the charts or single values for the gauges). These charting controls are bound to their datasource through the data binding mechanism. 
Now, I need a way to feed the incoming serial data to the data sources of the other UserControls so that they will display the incoming data in real-time.

There doesn't seem to be a native mechanism to exchange  or even would say distribute data from one User Control to other UserControls, at least not that I am aware of ;-/

I do have the code of the current "sample" application, it is however quite long. So to keep it simple, I decided to leave it out. I am not expecting anyone here to provide  a code response, but rather a pointer to documentation that tackles such issues of distributing data from one UserControl to others, if there is such thing, so that I would be able to solve the problem on my own.
Or perhaps just a suggestion how this could be done.

I tried to get to the main window handle  so to be able to get to its children,  but failed to get any instances of the objects generated by the XAML.

I hope someone has a suggestion .. if you need I will be glad to post relevant code snippets
Thank you and regards
Paolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread that reads the data should be encapsulated in a class of its own. Than create one instance of this class and pass that instance to all the user controls that need to access the data.
Naturally, the data the thread reads should be written into a data structure owned by the new class, not by the SerialPort control as currently.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply and suggestion. 
The problem with that is that the serial port is the one that drives the data process, passing it to the usercontrol as an instantiated object, would require to register a "data available" event in the receiving control, which then would call back the serial port object and get the data.

Comment: I rather do the opposite ... that is pass to the serial port the other control object and then their public method to update the datasource. In C++ it's easy to get the pointer to the controls via main window handle, but under C#WPF.. I have no clue

Comment: In the mean time I found this [link]( http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2012/08/27/a-communication-system-for-xaml-applications.aspx) which does exactly what I need, it is just an overhead, but is very elegant .. so I will use it. I am not sure if there is direct way to get to the control objects without coding a messaging system. Probably not ...